# combining module.exports next js

Tags: sass, next.js

I have a next js project where one `module.exports` can run but both can't run at the same time. How do I combine both module exports?

The `module.exports = withSass({` is confusing me. How can this be added to the `module.exports` above it

```
// next.config.js
module.exports = {
  serverRuntimeConfig: { // Will only be available on the server side
    mySecret: 'secret'
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: { // Will be available on both server and client
    staticFolder: '/static',
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  }
}

const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')
module.exports = withSass({
  /* config options here */
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So with next.js options, you simply move them into the nextConfig-argument you send to `withSass()`, like so:

```js
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass')

module.exports = withSass({
    serverRuntimeConfig: {
    mySecret: 'secret'
  },
  publicRuntimeConfig: {
    staticFolder: '/static',
    appId: 'XXXXXXXXXX',
    apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
  }
})
```

Comment: My issue was middleware related, thanks for the help this solved it!

Comment: No problem, glad to be helpful :)